# Run the SSIS Package when deployed to azure

Tags: ssis

I have deployed an SSIS package to Azure Cloud. When I try to migrate data from on-premise to the azure cloud, it gives the following error

> A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online.

I have created a virtual network in azure, however, cannot somehow access the virtual network while creating an Integration Runtime. Can anyone suggest any solution for the same?

Comment: So by "deployed to the cloud", you mean that you have deployed to an ADF SSIS-Azure runtime. And I guess you are trying to connect to an on premise server? Is the virtual network connected to the on-premises network? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/join-azure-ssis-integration-runtime-virtual-network

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to on prem files, but there are limitations around single windows credentials and authentication.  Take a look at [Connect to on-premises data sources and Azure file shares with Windows Authentication in SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-connect-with-windows-auth?view=sql-server-2017)